# is It possible that beal's conjecture can be solved using wiles' proof?

Tags: number-theory

Does Wiles proof of FLT contribute some pointers to beal's conjecture to enable to get it solved?

Comment: Well, afaik there has been no connection found relating general Beal's conjecture to elliptic curve theory, so answer is probably "no".

Comment: Fermat's Last Theorem is a corollary of Beal's Conjecture. Whether there's a further connection, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is perhaps worth noting that the explicit $abc$-conjecture would prove [Beal' s conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beal's_conjecture), too. By the $abc$-conjecture we would know that there are only finitely many counterexamples. With an explicit constant $C>0$ however, there would be an algorithm to determine all rational solutions, using  explicit bounds on the heights of the rational points in Falting's theorem (of his proof of the Mordell conjecture).

The $abc$-conjecture is equivalent to the (modified) Szpiro conjecture on elliptic curves, so there might be a further connection to elliptic curves.

Comment: Can a general Diophantine equation for all powers (FLT) have the desired answer?

Comment: What do you mean by "desired answer" ?